# Why Django Query for Two DateTimeFields Equality Does Not Work?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model:

```py
class Host(models.Model):
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I would like to filter out all objects that have create_date.date() == update_date.date(), so I use this Django Query:

```py
Host.objects.filter(create_date__date=F("update_date__date")).count()
```

Assuming, my database does have hosts that have create_date.date() == update_date.date(), so I expect the return value for `count()` > 0; however, I get 0 as the result.

Meanwhile, if I use this query:

```py
Host.objects.filter(create_date__date__lt=F("update_date__date")).count()
```

I will get my expected result.

In addition to that, I have

```py
a = Host.objects.filter(create_date__date__lt=F("update_date__date")).count()

b = Host.objects.filter(create_date__date__lte=F("update_date__date")).count()

a == b # True
```

From the above `a==b # True`, I think the `e` in `lte` does not take effect, which means that there are no cases that my two dates are the same, but there are in my scenario.

**Question**:
Why cannot I do equality comparison for Django query on DateTimeField?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the equality operation by using queryset constraint (Q objects)

```
Host.objects.filter(Q(create_date__date=F("update_date__date"))).count()
```

This should select all instances for which the date equals.

Another workable solution would be to use both `gt` and `lt` constraints to check for their equality when they are both not `true`

Comment: Why do I have to use `Q` here and cannot just use the normal query without `Q`? Plus, more clarification in the question

Comment: Its an interesting question. I am though not able to find an exact answer from  my research, and the docs are no helpful on this. The closest answer I can find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10048320/6505847). The `q` was just a suggestion to see if it would work, there's no real rational behind the use of it in this case

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! After trying, I still do not understand why it does not work.

Comment: Lol. this was answered nearly year and a half ago, I dont even know what I answered. You may want to see if there's any new questions relating to this on Stackoverflow